# URL re-write for indexed pages

Tags: seo, url-rewriting

I have a blog with around 40 posts, and i want to change the URL structure these posts. this is my old URL something like:

```
http://domain.com/blog/2013/02/04/string-here.html
```

i want to set the URL like:

```
http://domain.com/blog/category/string-here/
```

Now the concern is recently i have get the PR to my site after a long struggle ;)

i am using wordpress for my blog, and will do url rewriting easily,
i just want to know should i have to use 301 permanent redirection so that i will not get the 404 page not found error for my old pages??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you should use a 301 Redirect if the pages are going to move to the new URL structure permanently. The new structure is an improvement in terms of readability also.

Comment: **i have get the PR to my site**; is that re-writing effect on my website PR?

Comment: For PR (I am presuming you are talking about Google Page Rank here) this is the advised way to redirect pages. See http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=93633 for the full write up from Google.

Comment: @webomnizz A 301 redirect does pass PageRank, however, it does not necessarily pass it all (according to [Matt Cutts, Google](http://www.stonetemple.com/articles/interview-matt-cutts-012510.shtml)). But as joesk states, a 301 is the tool to use here. (And PR isn't everything.)

Comment: @w3d one last think i want to know, for how long i have to set the 301 redirection in my `.htaccess` file? until not cached from google?? or till the domain exist?

Comment: @webomnizz: For as long as possible. After a month or so Google should have updated its index, but for all the other (back)links to your site that don't get automatically updated the redirections will need to stay in place.

Comment: @w3d  i had this point about (back)links, i was not so clear. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

In terms of SEO, mod_rewrite can be helpful if you have complex URLs that contain more than 2 parameters. In other words, if one of your dynamic URLs is accessed, the mechanism behind mod_rewrite will "translate" it into a shorter, friendlier, static-looking URL.

- [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html)
- [free online URL rewriting](http://www.seochat.com/seo-tools/url-rewriting/)